# Put id in input hidden, working with jTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm working with `jquery.ajax()` I'm getting a object and I use jTemplate to write the html. My problem is now that I need to place the id of the object in a input hidden. I have no idea how I should do this. I tried to do a `<script>` in the template.htm with jquery to place the id in hidden but with no luck.

Any suggestions?

this is my jTemplate html file

```
<div style="background-color: #ccc">
    {$T.Email}
</div>

<div style="background-color: #ddd">
    {$T.Password}
</div>
```

This is my jquery

```
$('a').live('click', function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "GetUserWeb.asmx/GetUser",
                    data: "{'value': '" + id + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        ApplyTemplate(msg);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, err) {
                        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });

            function ApplyTemplate(msg) {
                $('#Container').setTemplateURL('template.htm');
                $('#Container').processTemplate(msg.d);
            }
```

Comment: I don't see an `id=""` on anything you posted to replace, can you describe a bit more?

Comment: I don't know how to place the id as value to the hiddenfield that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place the id in a JavaScript variable outside the function then you can access it in the template simply by putting {ItHere} in the template.

So do var id outside the function, and set it within the function.

```
var id;
$('a').live('click', function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                id = $(this).attr('id');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "GetUserWeb.asmx/GetUser",
                    data: "{'value': '" + id + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        ApplyTemplate(msg);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, err) {
                        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });

            function ApplyTemplate(msg) {
                $('#Container').setTemplateURL('template.htm');
                $('#Container').processTemplate(msg.d);
            }
```

Then you can add the id in the template like this:

```
<img src="HelloWorld.jpg" id="{id}"/>
```